# How to integrate GitLab and Codecov safely?

Tags: continuous-integration

When trying to sign up as a GitLab user on Codecov they request full admin access to my entire account. That is just not going to happen, so is there a way to set it up safely without hosting my own Codecov service? The [Codecov documentation](https://documentation.codeship.com/general/about/permissions/#gitlab) seems to indicate that it's not possible, but that seems to be based on an outdated version of the GitLab application scopes.